# How to attach files smtplib?

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm using this code to send mails using smtplib, is there any way to attach two   .xlsx  files in the mail?

```
import smtplib
msg = 'funny_text'
fromaddr = 'random_mail@gmail.com'
toaddrs  = ['random_mail@gmail.com', 'random_mail@gmail.com']
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
asunto = 'random_subject'
server.starttls()
server.login("login_mail@gmail.com", "great_password")
print('From: ' + fromaddr)
print('To: ' + str(toaddrs))
print('Subject: ' +asunto)
print('Message: ' + msg)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `msg.attach()` with `MIMETypes` see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)